# MvxRecyclerView and HttpClient.SendAsync

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mono, httpclient, mvvmcross

I have an issue with MvxRecyclerView and HttpClient.SendAsync

Specifically, at the point HttpClient.SendAsync receives the HttpResponseMessage back from the server, my MvxRecyclerView becomes jerky and unresponsive for a few seconds. As i allow synchronisation of data with the server constantly whilst the user is inputting information, this becomes a fairly frustrating issue.

My MvxRecyclerView is relatively complex, with potentially 30 different templates in the MvxTemplateSelector. However, the majority of the time the MvxRecyclerView performs flawlessly, displaying the correct templates and scrolling smoothly. If i enable Airplane Mode on the device, thus preventing server synchronisation from taking place, i have no issues at all.
Through trial-and-error, i have pinpointed the exact point at which it becomes unresponsive, and it appears to be the LoadIntoBufferAsync method from the HttpClient mono android base class
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/22da2fe31ef898e7021fad59521ee0b329d37b07/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpContent.cs#L137

If I cut down the complexity of the MvxItemTemplate and only return one Template regardless of the Item type, then i again have no issues at all.

This appears to be a perfect storm between the processing of the item template as the MvxRecyclerView is being scrolled, and the point at whichthe HttpResponseMessage is received back onto the mobile device.

I have tried using ConfigureAwait(false) on the HttpClient.SendAsync call, and also running the Http Operations in an Android Service and on a different thread using Task.Run, but there is always an issue at the point of data return regardless.

I do some fairly heavy database processing with the data returned from the HttpResponseMessage and this does not affect the usage of the MvxRecyclerView at all.

Is this something anyone else has encountered with the HttpClient? Is there a way to ensure the UI Thread is never blocked using SendAsync?

Comment: How are you creating the HttpClient? Have you tried using the `AndroidClientHandler`?

Comment: Yes already using the AndroidClientHandler

I create an instance of the HttpClient and assign the AndroidClientHandler at the start of my sync process and re-use it until i no longer need it. I used to create new instances each time I synced but changed that in the hope it would help